# error while showing data over html in angularjs2

Tags: angular2-services

i am calling WebAPI from AngularJs 2 app, API return data and i assinging it to property of my Angular component but when i using this property over HTML its saying undefiend. Please help

Error message

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'BenefitId' of undefined
```

Below is my benefit.component.ts code

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BenefitService } from '../services/benefit.service';
import { IBenefit } from '../models/benefit';

@Component({

    templateUrl: 'app/Components/benefit.component.html'

})

export class BenefitComponent{

    constructor(private _benefitService: BenefitService) {  }

    benefits: any;
    msg: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.LoadUsers();
    }

    LoadUsers(): void {
        this._benefitService.get("http://localhost/MyApi/api/Get/1950/7775/1")
            .subscribe(benefits => { this.benefits = benefits; console.log(this.benefits); console.log('hi'); },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);

    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<table>
    <tr >
        <td>
            {{benefits.BenefitId}}
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

benefits is `undefined` till API returns a data, and of course you can't get property `BenefitId` of `undefined`.

So, just try:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.benefits = {};
  this.LoadUsers();
}
```

Comment: i fixed my issue by using safe navigation operation. {{benefits?.BenefitId}}